# Re-program Apple Keyboard Lock Key

Tags: keyboard, microphone, screen-lock

I have an [Apple Magic Keyboard](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MK2A3LL/A/magic-keyboard-us-english), and I'm hoping to reprogram the `Lock` key to be a push to talk key. Programs like [BetterTouchTool](https://folivora.ai/) can be used in congress with [Mic Drop](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/mic-drop-mute-manager/id1489816366?mt=12) to facilitate this happening with almost any other key. However, it seems that there are no settings available in the Keyboard Shortcut Settings section for Apple, and neither of these two programs can pick up the `Lock` key press, it simply takes me directly to the login screen.

Is there any way I can use this key (which I would never, ever use for its intended function) to somehow generate a more typical keystroke which can be sent to BetterTouchTool/Mic Drop to get some mute/unmute or push-to-talk functionality going? Does anyone have any ideas? Thank you so much for your time and advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org) to remap your key. As I infer that you have a Magic Keyboard without the Touch ID, which the Karabiner supports from v13.7.5.

Comment: Thank you so much. For others looking for this solution, in Karabiner Elements you'll go to `Media controls > Lock key on Magic Keyboard without Touch ID`.

Comment: Glad to be of help.